# appengine dispatch.yaml does not find my module?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Why do I get the following error using this dispatch configuration?

https://github.com/gertcuykens/gcl-11/tree/master/server%20go

[image]

```
Mac:server go gert$ /Users/gert/Desktop/IdeaProjects/toolbox/serve.sh dispatch.yaml www/www.yaml default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gert/Documents/sdk-appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 82, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/gert/Documents/sdk-appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 78, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/gert/Documents/sdk-appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 970, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/gert/Documents/sdk-appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 963, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Users/gert/Documents/sdk-appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 714, in start
    options.config_paths, options.app_id)
  File "/Users/gert/Documents/sdk-appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 678, in __init__
    'file.' % sorted(missing_modules))
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.InvalidAppConfigError: Modules [u'www'] specified in dispatch.yaml are not defined by a yaml file.
Mac:server go gert$
```

The modules do work without a dispatch.yaml?

```
Mac:server go gert$ /Users/gert/Desktop/IdeaProjects/toolbox/serve.sh www/www.yaml default
INFO     2014-08-24 22:26:51,886 sdk_update_checker.py:242] Checking for updates to the SDK.
WARNING  2014-08-24 22:26:52,241 api_server.py:383] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-08-24 22:26:52,244 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:58746
INFO     2014-08-24 22:26:52,249 dispatcher.py:183] Starting module "wwww" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-08-24 22:26:52,253 dispatcher.py:183] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8081
INFO     2014-08-24 22:26:52,256 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out "www" is a special name if I rename it to for example "static" it works... god$^*(&^)it!